# Zend framework, YouTube API, default title (Browserbased upload)

Tags: php, zend-framework, metadata, youtube-api, title

I got this code for uploading videos to my youtubeaccount from my website:

```
<?php  

session_start();
    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '150M');
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '30M');
    ini_set('default_socket_timeout', '6000');
    ini_set('max_input_time', '6000');
    ini_set('post_max_size', '100M');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', '6000');
    $clientLibraryPath = 'library';
    $oldPath = set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $clientLibraryPath);

//include Zend Gdata Libs  
require_once("Zend/Gdata/ClientLogin.php");  
require_once("Zend/Gdata/HttpClient.php");  
require_once("Zend/Gdata/YouTube.php");  
require_once("Zend/Gdata/App/MediaFileSource.php");  
require_once("Zend/Gdata/App/HttpException.php");  
require_once('Zend/Uri/Http.php');  

//yt account info  
$yt_user = 'xx'; //youtube username or gmail account  
$yt_pw = 'xx'; //account password  
$yt_source = 'xx'; //name of application (can be anything) 

//yt dev key  
$yt_api_key = 'xx'; //your youtube developer key  

//login in to YT  
$authenticationURL= 'https://www.google.com/youtube/accounts/ClientLogin';  
$httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(  
                                          $username = $yt_user,  
                                          $password = $yt_pw,  
                                          $service = 'youtube',  
                                          $client = null,  
                                          $source = $yt_source, // a short string identifying your application  
                                          $loginToken = null,  
                                          $loginCaptcha = null,  
                                          $authenticationURL);  



$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $yt_source, NULL, $yt_api_key);  

$myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();  

$myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle('The Movie');
$myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription('My Test Movie');
$myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory('Autos');
$myVideoEntry->SetVideoTags('cars, funny');


$tokenHandlerUrl = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken';
$tokenArray = $yt->getFormUploadToken($myVideoEntry, $tokenHandlerUrl);
$tokenValue = $tokenArray['token'];
$postUrl = $tokenArray['url'];

// place to redirect user after upload
$nextUrl = 'http://sabinequardon.dk';

// build the form
$form = '<form id="youtube_upload" action="'. $postUrl .'?nexturl='. $nextUrl .
        '" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="uploader">'. 
        '<input id="title" name="video_title" type="text"/>'.
        '<input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file"/>'. 
        '<input name="token" type="hidden" value="'. $tokenValue .'"/>'.
        '<input value="Upload Video File" type="submit" id="submit" />'. 
        '</form>
';

echo $form; 
?>
```

I'm not really good at PHP, and it's the first time I'm trying to use the YouTube API. Been reading everything I could, just didn't seem to help much.
I know it's something that I get the metadata first before uploading the video?

I need the user to write their own title, so all the video's aren't named the same thing.

Is there a way to do this?
I've tried looking everywhere, just can't seem to find the right answer.
Just annoying if all the videos the users are uploading are called the same.

Thank you.

Comment: Where did you get the code? Does it work as it is?

Comment: I mixed it together myself by looking around the internet. It works. Videos gets uploaded, but all with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

This line sets the video title:

```
$myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle('The Movie');
```

As you already have an input for the title in the form, you can simply use it:

```
$video_title = $_POST['video_title'];
$myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle($video_title);
```

Or simply:

```
$myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle($_POST['video_title']);
```

Comment: and how will it help if we will send file straight to youtube (by zend client login)? what about if we sends it not through our host?